# Installing Fedora 11 fIlesystem from ISO in to a VM image

Tags: virtualization, fedora

I need to install Fedora 11 in my monitor-less linux box which is running some where in a data center. I will use Fedora 11 as a virtual machine.

What I already know/have:

1) How to create LVM partitions and create ext3 filesystem
2) Mount the LVM partition and ISO image
3) Run the partition with Xen as a virtual machine

What I need:

1) I need to install Fedora ll file system into an lvm partition (let's say /dev/fedora11) from an ISO image so that I have all the directories /root, /bin, /sys etc etc under /dev/fedora11

Any help would be much appreciated!

## NOTE: I don't have a monitor for this server, so I need to do it via SSH

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into [kickstart](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Anaconda/Kickstart) for automated installation.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want a paravirtualized guest, here is one way of doing it.

Install your Fedora 11 ISO on another system (provisioning server) that you have network and NFS access to.  Say you install it as /FEDORA/fedora.iso.  On this system create a subdirectory called /FEDORA/ISO and mount fedora.iso on /FEDORA/ISO using the loop, iso9660 options. Then export /FEDORA/ISO as rw,no_root_squash in /etc/exports.

On your system use virt-install with the nographics option (--nographics) to provision the Fedora 11 client guest. The location path (-l, --location) is nfs://provisioningserver/FEDORA/ISO.

Answer (score 0):

You may configure vnc for your xen, start virtual machine from cdrom and with vnc and install Fedora as usual.

Here is a couple of howtos:

- http://www.virtuatopia.com/index.php/Configuring_a_VNC_based_Graphical_Console_for_a_Xen_Paravirtualized_domainU_Guest
- http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Xen/InstallingHVMDomU

Another option is to use virt-install tool from libvirt: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/rhel-centos-xen-virtualization-installation-howto.html